# In linux, how to launch a program(ex.sublime text) in terminal in any directory?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to do the following thing:
In a terminal that is in any directory, type: "sublime a.txt"
And sublime text will open a.txt in the current directory.
I know i need to somehow write some script but how?
One of my friends has done it once but i forgot.

Comment: on linux you should just be able to type `subl` from anywhere

Comment: @chris sorry it doesn't work

Comment: 1) When you write a Linux shell script ... the script will do the same kinds of things you'd do from the command line.  For example, if you type "sublime a.txt", then your script would also contain "sublime a.txt".  Or "subl $1" (to "parameterize" argument #1.  2) The reason "it works from anywhere" ... is that the command "sublime" happens to be in your [$PATH](http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/1122-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-path-variable) variable.  3) Here's a [shell scripting](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that for a Linux scripting question to be on-topic for StackOverflow, you need to know how to do it by hand.  Otherwise it's a "usage of particular linux command" or "configuration of my linux box" question, which belongs on SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the folder where you have `sublime` to your `PATH`. Assuming that is "$HOME/Sublime Text 2/" that might look like

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Sublime Text 2"
```

and you might also need an alias

```
alias sublime=sublime_text
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know where the sublime text is.
For example, /usr/bin.
Edit the profile of the user

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

Then, re-longin the user with - option (which will execute the profile.)
Now this user can start the sublime text in any directory.

Comment: The example is rather academic because `/usr/bin` is certain to already be on the user's `PATH`.  The question should be updated with information about where `sublime` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you write a Linux shell script ... the script will do the same kinds of things you'd do from the command line.

For example, if you type "sublime a.txt", then your script would also contain "sublime a.txt". Or "sublime $1" (to "parameterize" argument #1).

Here is a simple shell scripting tutorial (one of many you can easily find on the web):  http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

2) The reason "it works from anywhere" ... is that the command "sublime" happens to be in your [$PATH](http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/1122-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-path-variable) variable.

If "sublime" is installed in a "standard directory" (like "/usr/bin"), then you shouldn't need to change your $PATH - it should just work automatically.

3) If you successfully type "sublime a.txt" (or "subl a.txt") from a command line on one PC ... but the same command fails on a different PC ... then maybe sublime just isn't installed on the second PC.

Here are instructions for installing on Fedora/RedHat/Centos (if that happens to be your OS:

http://digitizor.com/2014/06/30/install-sublime-text-editor-3-fedora-redhat/

Otherwise, you should be able to install sublime with the standard tools "apt-get" or "yum".